# Hibernate update an entity with a transient object

Tags: java, hibernate, transient

I was wandering what is the best approach to this scenario:
I have a table and I want to update a row in the table. I am given a new transient object that relates to one of the lines in the table but some of the information is different (this is the info that needs to be updated).
I retrieve the object from the DB and now have one persistent object and one transient that needs to update DB object.

I am using Hibernate and MySql.

what is the best approach.

EDIT: the object is extremely complex with foreign keys to other tables.

Thanks,
Ronen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the transient object persistent. You do that by associating with a session as follows

```
DomesticCat fritz = new DomesticCat();
fritz.setColor(Color.GINGER);
fritz.setSex('M');
fritz.setName("Fritz");
sess.update(fritz);
```

You can use the persistent object to to set the values of the transient object as follows

```
.
.
.
fritz.setColor(persistentObject.getColor());
fritz.setId(persistentObject.getId());
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.but wont that create a new entry with the same data. I want to update the existing row and not create duplicate row. also The entity (my Domestic cat) is extreamly complex with foreign keys to other tables

Comment: @rperez: If the new object has the same ID as an existing database row, then no, it will update that row.

Comment: Tom, the new object has no ID as it is transient and the ID generation policy is that ID is set upon saving. I cannot manually set and update as the row already associated with the persistent object. what am I missing?

Comment: so you mean something like this (fritz.setId(persistentObject.getId());
) doesn't work?

Comment: after I do fritz.setId(persistentObject.getId()); I try to do hibernateSession.update(fritz) and I get MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException since one of the fields is unique, how can I tell hibernate not to update it?

Comment: Use hibernateSession.merge(fritz)